# Get value from json "undefined" what I have wrong?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this string:

```
[
 {"id":"001",
  "name":"Charlie"},
  {"id":"002",
  "name":"Ellie"},
]
```

Them, I save this string in a variable and I parse it:

```
function parseJSON(string){
   var mylovelyJSON = JSON.stringify(string); 
   alert(mylovelyJSON[id]); 
}
```

When I make my alert, I get and "undefined", I also tried with "mylovelyJSON.id", And I get the same.

Could not be a Json? I get this string from an php array.

Comment: You parse it wrong, should be `JSON.parse(string); `

Comment: With json.parse I get "object Object],[object Object]" I dont get the value of my id´s.

Comment: Are you trying to reference it by "001" or the index of the array? And you are making a string, not an object. `stringify` is taking an object and making a string. If it is producing object, object, than you already have an object and do not need to parse it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are many things wrong here

## Your JSON is invalid

You have an extra `,` just before the end of the array that you need to remove

## You need to parse

`JSON.stringify` converts a JavaScript data structure into a string of JSON.

You need to go the other way and use `JSON.parse`.

## Square-bracket notation takes strings

`mylovelyJSON[id]` takes the value of `id` (which is undeclared so, in this case, would throw a reference error) and gets the property with the name that is the same as that value.

You need either `mylovelyJSON["id"]` or `mylovelyJSON.id`

## You have an array

Your JSON consists of an array of objects, not a single object.

You need to get an object out of the array before you can access properties on it.

`mylovelyJSON[0]["id"]`

---

```js
var json_text = '[{"id":"001","name":"Charlie"},{"id":"002","name":"Ellie"}]';

parseJSON(json_text);

function parseJSON(string){
   var result_of_parsing_json = JSON.parse(string);
   document.body.appendChild(
     document.createTextNode(result_of_parsing_json[0]["id"])
   );
}
```

Comment: I think this really answered by question. Also, more people can use this method of variable naming while answering queries instead of honestly bar/foo or a, x. Well done.

Comment: I did not saw any answer like this. Well documented. Step by step solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Two things are wrong here

1. Your array ends with a comma, which isn't valid json
2. You are converting a string to javascript, and stringify does the opposite of that.

So something like this might work:

```
var id = 0;

function parseJSON(string){
    var mylovelyJSON = JSON.parse(string); 
    alert(mylovelyJSON[id]); 
}
```

**Note** I am assuming that `id` is a global variable...